# Meteor 1.6 build error logs

Tags: meteor, logging

I have a problem building my Meteor 1.6 app. The building process gets stuck at:
=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.

I don't see any errors and I can't reach my app.
I updated all meteor and npm packages...
Anyone an idea where I could find hidden errors?

Comment: Try to run your app with `meteor run --verbose`

Comment: Even with --verbose I don't get any errors...

Comment: You could try to remove meteor globally and then reinstall and try again.

Comment: try with `METEOR_PROFILE=100`, that should tell you which build steps are taking longer than 100ms

Comment: Also before meteor reinstall, try deleting `.meteor/local` to wipe it's cache first

Comment: I deleted the app, created an empty meteor project and copied all my code back into it...When I also copied the package lists into it, I ran into the same problem. Installing all packages seperately again fixed the issue.